# IntelliJ with gatling doesn´t find simulations to run

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, karate

I'm having issue with IntelliJ with gatling.

When I run the test, gating returns a message refering that "No simulations to run"

```
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- gatling-maven-plugin:3.0.5:test (default) @ com.ffTests ---
[ERROR] No simulations to run
No simulations to run

Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoFailureException: No simulations to run
    at io.gatling.mojo.GatlingMojo.simulations (GatlingMojo.java:372)
    at io.gatling.mojo.GatlingMojo.execute (GatlingMojo.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:564)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:
```

The code I'm is the follow:

```
package Performance
import com.intuit.karate.gatling.PreDef._
import io.gatling.core.Predef._
import scala.concurrent.duration._

class performanceGo extends Simulation{

  val getReason = scenario("login").exec(karateFeature("classpath:performance/TestPerformance.feature"))

 setUp(
    getReason.inject(rampUsers( users= 10).during(10 seconds))
    )
}
```

The above class must execute a cucumber feature called TestPerformance.feature.

The pom dependencies are

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.intuit.karate</groupId>
            <artifactId>karate-apache</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.5</version>
        </dependency>            
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.intuit.karate</groupId>
            <artifactId>karate-junit5</artifactId>
             <version>0.9.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.intuit.karate</groupId>
            <artifactId>karate-gatling</artifactId>
            <version>${karate.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

The plugins I'm using are

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.compiler.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                    <compilerArgument>-Werror</compilerArgument>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.2</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>io.gatling</groupId>
                <artifactId>gatling-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <simulationsFolder>src/test/java</simulationsFolder>
                    <includes>
                        <include>mock.CatsKarateSimulation</include>
                    </includes>
                        <disableCompiler>true</disableCompiler>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>io.gatling.frontline</groupId>
                <artifactId>frontline-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>package</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

The scala plugin version is "2019.3.17" and I'm using jre1.8.0_241.

Do you have an idea of what may be happening?

Comment: no and I suggest you try the example project first, and then compare. if still stuck - follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Answer (score 3):

May be simply because you haven't pointed to the right scala file. You are using a package called `Performance` but your `pom.xml` refers to `mock.CatsKarateSimulation`.

Comment: thanks, I changed it to:
```
     <simulationsFolder>src/test/java</simulationsFolder>
                    <includes>
                        <include>Performance</include>
                    </includes>
```
but didn´t solve.

Comment: @CarlosRodrigues see my comment below your question

Answer (score 1):

This issue was related with pom.xm and JAVA_Home variable.

Solution:

java_home = "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14"

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>org.example</groupId>
<artifactId>com.ffTests</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <maven.compiler.version>3.6.0</maven.compiler.version>
    <karate.version>0.9.5</karate.version>
    <gatling.plugin.version>3.0.2</gatling.plugin.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.intuit.karate</groupId>
        <artifactId>karate-apache</artifactId>
        <version>${karate.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.intuit.karate</groupId>
        <artifactId>karate-gatling</artifactId>
        <version>${karate.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <testResources>
        <testResource>
            <directory>src/test/java</directory>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </testResource>
    </testResources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven.compiler.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                <source>${java.version}</source>
                <target>${java.version}</target>
                <compilerArgument>-Werror</compilerArgument>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>io.gatling</groupId>
            <artifactId>gatling-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${gatling.plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <simulationsFolder>src/test/java</simulationsFolder>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```